# Find all common subsequences of given two strings

Tags: java, algorithm

I have tried using the LCS(Longest Common Subsequence) algorithm, but I want subsequences of all lengths. How do we modify the LCS Code?

**Example**: Given `String_1="abxcd"` and `String_2="aybcd"` LCS results in `"abcd"` but I would like to display { "a", "ab", "bcd", "cd", "abcd", "d" }

Comment: Welcome on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you interested in the [Longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) or the [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)?

Comment: I want all subsequences of two strings Example: String_1="abxcd" and String_2="aybcd" LCS will give "abcd" but I would like to display a,ab,bcd,cd,abcd,d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pseudo code

```
Set allCS;//create an empty set
String[] subStrings = getSubSequences(String_2) //find the subsequence of String_2
for (String str : subStrings) 
    allCS.put(LCS(String_1,str)) //add LCS of (String_1,str) to allCS
```

Note :

- `getSubSequences(String s)` returns all the subsequence of the given string parameter
- `LCS(String s1, String s2)` returns the LCS of s1 and s

Comment: I am expecting subsequences not substrings.

Comment: @Sanjana- I just edited my answer, and you can see the general approach is the same.

Comment: I have tried doing this way, but for longer strings, I don't think this works out. Can you suggest me any other way to do it.

Comment: @Sanjana- What are your limitations exactly? Is your problem with memory or run time? I suggest you to copy and paste my pseudocode and ask a new question, and request for a more efficient way. Obviously you'll get more answers that way. If you inform me, I'll answer according to your requirements too.